# Spring boot - how to disable error handling with html?

Tags: spring-boot

## Context

In my yaml I have:

```
server:
  port: 8081
  ssl:
    enabled: false
  max-http-request-header-size: 102400
  error:
    whitelabel:
      enabled: false

  ...
```

and controller advice:

```
@RestControllerAdvice
@Slf4j
public class DefaultControllerAdvice {

    ...

    @ExceptionHandler(value = {Exception.class})
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleException(Exception exception) {
        var incidentId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        log.error(INCIDENT_ID_MESSAGE + incidentId, exception);
        return ResponseEntity.status(INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
                .contentType(APPLICATION_JSON)
                .body(ExceptionDto.builder()
                        .incidentId(incidentId)
                        .message("There was internal server error")
                        .build());
    }
```

## Problem

When I type in browser: `localhost:8081` I'm receiving `500` error status code.

`localhost:8081` --> root is not registered in any controller. I wanted to test advice.

I expected `404` but problem is that in logs there's no info about true cause.

When I go to log I see:

```
org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.NoResourceFoundException: No static resource .
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler.handleRequest(ResourceHttpRequestHandler.java:585)
    at 

2024-02-18T00:39:12.891+01:00 ERROR 17258 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] k.s.s.m.i.e.DefaultControllerAdvice      : incident id: 079a8e6e-74ab-4d9c-9c5a-c5b4693546d2

org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.NoResourceFoundException: No static resource favicon.ico.
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler.handleRequest(ResourceHttpRequestHandler.java:585)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.HttpRequestHandlerAdapter.handle(HttpRequestHandlerAdapter.java:52)
```

Right now even from logs or status code it's not clear what happened.

## Question

How to force spring boot to answer to any exception with json and not with HTML?

Answer (score 0):

#### Solution 1

Add these configuration to your application.yaml: (tested on spring boot 3.1)

```
spring:
  mvc:
    throw-exception-if-no-handler-found: true
  web:
    resources:
      add-mappings: false
```

Only works when serving static files is not required.

#### Solution 2

Upgrade your spring boot version to 3.2 or later.

#### Explaination

In early spring versions, if there's no handlers found, spring will try to find static files, which prevent the application handling '404 errors'.

The problem is mentioned at https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/38733

And is optimized in Spring 6: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/29491

Comment: I'm using spring boot `3.2.2`.  This settings not solved the problem.